# Javascript CSV download for UTF-8 character with BOM and Seperator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, utf-8, download

I have a javascript code to download csv and it has UTF-8 character in it.

If I don't use the 'sep=,\r\n', the UTF-8 char are display properly with BOM char in browser Chrome and Mozilla.

But it doesn't work with IE, as all the data comes in one column.

To resolve it, if i use 'sep=,\r\n', then the UTF-8 char are not display properly in all the 3 browsers.

It has to be manually import in excel by choosing encoding UTF-8.

I'm looking for a solution, where both BOM and separator can be used, and user can directly open the csv with excel by double clicking the file.

Code snippet:

```
tableString = 'sep=,\r\n' + tableString;
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {

                    myFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    myFrame.document.write(tableString);
                    myFrame.document.close();
                    myFrame.focus();
                    myFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName);
                } else {
                    csvData = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(tableString);
                    var link=document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('style', "visibility:hidden");
                    link.href=csvData;
                    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                    link.innerHTML = "Export CSV";
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
                }
```